# TOC with pagestyle empty in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir

I'm using the memoir class for a thesis, and want no page numbering of the front matter including the TOC. Have followed the answer to [Table of contents with page style empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/table-of-contents-with-page-style-empty) which does remove the page numbering of the first page of the TOC. My TOC is three pages long, and the last 2 pages still has a heading with roman page numbering. Minimal example below here:

```
\documentclass[danish,12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}} 

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \include{frontmatter/titlepage}
  \include{frontmatter/abstract}
  \tableofcontents*
  \pagestyle{headings}

  \mainmatter
  ...
```

Comment: Put the `\pagestyle{empty}` command before `\frontmatter`.

Comment: Gave it a try but does not cause any change in output.

Comment: Did you delete your .aux files and rerun latex twice?

Comment: Did now, still same result. I also tried adding a \AtEndDocument.. which strangely enough removed the header from the 2nd page of the TOC bot not the third. I'm using pdflatex from MikTek if it makes any difference.

Comment: Try putting `\clearpage` after the `\tableofcontents*` command.

Comment: That did it!! Thank you very much for the effort, want to add an answer?

Comment: I've incorporated the comment discussion into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `memoir` doesn't automatically start contents lists on a new page, you need to issue `\clearpage` commands to make sure that the page style gets associated correctly. Headers and footers are added after the page content is produced, so the `\clearpage` is necessary.  The standard document classes incorporate `\clearpage` into some of these commands, but `memoir` chooses not to.

```
\documentclass[danish,12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}} 

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\include{frontmatter/titlepage}
\include{frontmatter/abstract}
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage % TOC will now have the previous pagestyle setting
\pagestyle{headings}

\mainmatter
  ...
\end{document}
```