# Table of contents pagestyle

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~ - ~#1}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter~ - ~#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textsc\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textsc\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
    {
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Nice titles and all
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
    This is a very nice abstract.
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

There is one problem: after the table of contents (which is now one page and I think will stay one page) the doubleclearpage makes the empty page I want, but it keeps the header with contents in it, even though I tell him to take the plain pagestyle. It seems that tableofcontents likes his own pagestyle. How can I fix this? Note: I have considered other questions regarding similar questions ([Table of contents with page style empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5787/91138)) but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: you don't need all these `\thispagestyle{plain}` only one `\pagestyle{plain}` before `abstract` and then `\pagestyle{fancy}` before your first chapter.

Comment: by the way, you can use `\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}` or `\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, 11pt]{report}` and avoid  `\cleardoublepage`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scrextend`. Then you can set the page style used on blank pages (pages inserted by `\cleardoublepage`) as package option `cleardoublepage=<value>`. Possible values are `empty` (default), `plain`, `current` or the name of another page style.

The value of the option can be changed inside the document using `\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=<value>}`.

There are also new commands like `\cleardoubleemtypage`, `\cleardoubleplainpage`, `\cleardoublestandardpage` to set the page style just for this single blank page.

In the following example I use option `cleardoublepage=plain` and a `\cleardoubleemptypage` after the title page and the abstract.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[cleardoublepage=plain]{scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength\headheight{13.6pt}% as suggested by fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~ - ~#1}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter~ - ~#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textsc\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textsc\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
    {
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    }
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Nice titles and all
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoubleemptypage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
    This is a very nice abstract.
\end{abstract}
\cleardoubleemptypage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```